# Knockout asyncCommand / Ajax MVC ActionResults

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am pretty new to front end development and also the project I’m working on (bug fixes). I am using Knockout/MVC ActionResults.

I have been tasked to alter a form so that it doesn't allow double click submission, I added basic Jquery to disable to button, but have been told it needs to use asyncCommand.

What I have noted about it however is that all examples using this they return a Json result etc. where mine will be an action result.

I was wondering if I need to alter the MVC actionresult or whether there is another way that I’m just not seeing.

I was hoping I could do something like:

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-action" data-bind="command: create, activity: create.isExecuting">Create</button>
```

JS

```
 model.create = ko.asyncCommand({
        execute: function (complete) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/account/create",
                data: ko.toJSON(data),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            });
        complete();
        },
        canExecute: function (isExecuting) {
            return !isExecuting;
        }
    });
```

CONTROLLER

```
        public ActionResult Create(Model model, int versionId)
        {

if (success)
                {
                    return Redirect("/accounts");
                }
else
                {
                    return View(model);
                }
}
```

Can this actually happen or not?

Thanks,

Clare

Comment: return View can be used but redirect will not work in ajax call

Comment: It doesnt seem to mind the Redirect however it is not noting a change (button has been clicked) and is allowing another button click to happen. I think I need to do something else within the execute section but i dont know what

Comment: How many buttons are you trying to coordinate?  Your post only mentions a single button, but your comment suggests multiple buttons...

Comment: One button 'Create' dependent on whether the create user is added depends on where it goes.Success return Redirect("/accounts"); Error return View(model);

Comment: Is it calling 'Create' fine however however the canExecute is set wrong as it allows me to double click. I think i need to add something to the execute function but i dont know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to alter the ActionResult to return a value to AJAX.